# How do i do an SQL LEFT JOIN with a WHERE CLAUSE AND ORDER BY? Details in the Description

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm making a program that displays Advertisement Records and their transactions.

I have these 3 tables `customer_tb`, `mediaadv_tb` and `contracts_tb`.

I have foreign keys in `contracts_tb`, mainly the id references from `customer_tb` and `mediaadv_tb`.

What I want to display in one table are the following:

```
contracts_tb.contract_id
    ,contracts_tb.media_idref referrences mediaadv_tb.media_id
    ,contracts_tb.customer_idref referrences customer_tb.cus_id
    ,
WHERE contracts_tb.STATUS = "Active" (I want TO show STATUS that are ONLY = "Active")
    ,customer_tb.firstname || ' ' || middlename || ' ' || lastname AS fullname
    ,customer_tb.company
    ,mediaadv_tb.title
    ,mediaadv_tb.previewimg then ordered BY hpd ASCENDING(hours per day which the ads must be played)
```

Here's the create statement query of my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE contracts_tb (
    contract_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    ,customer_idref INTEGER REFERENCES customer_tb(cus_id)
    ,media_idref INTEGER REFERENCES mediaadv_tb(med_id)
    ,STATUS TEXT
    ,hpd NUMERIC
    ,dateadded DATE
    ,dateexpiration TEXT
    ,amountpaid REAL
    ,arearofcoverage TEXT
    ) WITHOUT ROWID

CREATE TABLE customer_tb (
    cus_id TEXT NOT NULL
    ,company TEXT UNIQUE
    ,firstname TEXT
    ,middlename TEXT
    ,lastname TEXT
    ,gender TEXT
    ,dob DATE
    ,dateregistered DATE
    ,contactno TEXT
    ,emailaddress TEXT
    ,description TEXT
    ,cuspic BLOB
    ,PRIMARY KEY (cus_id)
    )

CREATE TABLE mediaadv_tb (
    med_id TEXT NOT NULL
    ,type TEXT
    ,title TEXT
    ,duration NUMERIC
    ,dateadded TEXT
    ,filepath TEXT
    ,previewimg BLOB
    ,PRIMARY KEY (med_id)
    );
```

Thank you for considering!

Comment: Looks to me like you've got SQLite here. I've tagged accordingly. If I am wrong, please fix your tags and tell us what DBMS you are using.

Comment: SQLite sorry forgot to tell. and the tags are limited to 4 for me.

Comment: Ok I understand, in the future letting people know which dbms is more important than the other tags. Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT a.firstname || ' ' || a.middlename || ' ' || a.lastname AS fullname,
       a.company,
       c.title,
       c.previewimg
  FROM customer_tb a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN contracts_tb b
    ON b.customer_idref = a.cus_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN mediaadv_tb c
    ON c.med_id = b.media_idref
 WHERE b.status = 'Active'
 ORDER BY b.hpd
```

Comment: Try it now, I fixed a typo